# How to find all factors of a number for a given number range

Tags: javascript

How can I find all the existing factors between two number?
for example all the factors of `5` that are between `10` and `1000`.

One thing I can think of is like this:

```js
function getFactors(factor, numbers) {
  let factors = new Array()
  
  for (var i = numbers[0] ; i <= numbers[1] ; i++) {
    if (i % factor == 0) factors.push(i)
  }

  return factors
}

console.log(getFactors(5, [50, 100]))
```

But the problem is that I have a big number range (`[0, 10000]`) and a small factor `0.01`. so I think doing this using my solution will be too much in terms of performance (i need to do this check every tick).

so I was wondering what is the better way to do this?

Comment: Looks like homework

Comment: @JamesAMohler nah, it's for a game i'm working on. i'm doing a score chart for it, so i need to find all factors between 0 and the current score of  the player to draw the chart, something like that

Comment: Is there ever a scenario where `numbers` aray has more than two elements? It looks like you are creating a function with three parameters.

Comment: @JamesAMohler no there will never bee such a scenario. it's two parameters, the factor and an array for numbers range. though i'm not sure what is your point here

Comment: @Adrin does your score increase by a fixed amount?

Comment: @obscure no it doesn't

Comment: I assume the factor is fixed though?

Comment: @obscure it is not actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve same thing without checking for every number between `numbers[0]` & numbers[1]. What you need basically is to get every multiple of `factor` between `numbers[0]` & `numbers[1]`. Below code does it:

```
function getFactors(factor, numbers) {
  let factors = new Array();
  let start = numbers[0]/factor;
  let end = numbers[1]/factor;
  for(var i=start; i<= end; i++) {
    factors.push(factor*i);
  }

  return factors
}
console.log(getFactors(5,[50,100]))
//[50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
```

Comment: Great !! Now extend this to find every prime between one billion and one trillion every millisecond

Comment: @AvinKavish I can't see `finding Prime numbers` anywhere in Question.

Comment: it was a joke :) I'm referring to the fact that finding primes is not solvable as easily as this. In fact, it is one of the hardest IIRC.

Comment: @AvinKavish :) knew but couldn't confirm(joke or not).